# Meaning of 'preach' in this context?

Tags: meaning

'He met a crooked woman and found a crooked *preach*'
-https://www.quotev.com/story/3012617/There-was-a-Crooked-Man/1
-Here it seems like a noun, but upon checking the dictionary there weren't any noun form of that word , except for an obsolete one which didn't quite go with the context.
-Can someone provide me with an appropriate meaning?

Comment: Is there any doubt as to the meaning? This is a poem (or rhyme), and, often such do not conform to dictionaries. Although not "proper" English, ministers  will be greeted with "Hey, preach!" from time to time.

Comment: NB - these lines are part of a little-known poem adapted from the traditional nursery rhyme. The original rhyme is only four lines, ending in "they all lived together in a little crooked house."

Comment: ^@Chappo well sometimes they end the stories/poem halfway or change the ending so that the kids don't have to encounter the gruesome part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preach appears to be short for preacher, as in the person who marries the crooked man to the crooked woman in the next line of the poem.